# Multi master openldap issue (str2entry: entry -1 has no dn)

Tags: openldap

i am running multimaster 4 node.
when the power has gone 3 node is running but one node has problems like this

```
Checking configuration files for slapd:                    [FAILED]
str2entry: entry -1 has no dn
slaptest: bad configuration file!
```

What is the problem? Please help me out.

Comment: What part of 'bad configuration file' don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a malformed configuration file. Also, it must not be compressed.

Answer (score 0):

The error `str2entry: entry -1 has no dn` is a follow up to "bad configuration file".

- check that you have not added any new "configuration files" under `/etc/ldap/slapd` (I had created a `backup.ldif` file with `slapcat`)
- configuration files might have been manually modified and they don't match with their checksum values.  See https://serverfault.com/a/518959/92516 and http://injustfiveminutes.com/2014/10/28/how-to-fix-ldif_read_file-checksum-error/

Bottom line: manual modifications to ldap configuration files. You're going to have bad times.